# how to add cannonical tag for ASPX .NET page

Tags: asp.net, seo

How could I set a cannonical tag for .NET (aspx) web pages that use master pages?
based on the SEO test, our site fails on the canonical test.  we are using a 3rd party  hoster (win server) and don't have access to root server!

I added the following snippet to my domain.com/default.aspx page

```
HtmlLink seoTag = new HtmlLink();

    seoTag.Attributes.Add("rel", "canonical");
    seoTag.Href = "http://www.domain.com/";
    Header.Controls.Add(seoTag);
```

but that didn't help!

Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Did this produce any output at all?  Are you able to simply add the element directly to the markup?  (That is, if the values are static, why even involve code-behind?)

Comment: it didn't produce any output.  please fee free to suggest a better way. My wehboster says, he made changes at IIS to correctly resolve to domain URL however, upon checkup its not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this in the aspx (html code)

```
<link rel=”canonical” href=”http://example.com/page.html”/>
```

[source](http://www.seoreviewtools.com/canonical-url-location-checker/)